# Passing deep link data in iOS App Install campaigns using Google Universal App Campaigns?

Tags: branch.io

Is it possible to pass deep link data for iOS App Install campaigns using Google/Adwords Universal App Campaigns?

For example, we want to pass unique identifier per App Install campaign and read it back when on first App open.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, with the new linkless integration, it is no longer possible to pass deep link data through Google's UAC. This is a limitation set by Google and there is nothing we can do to bypass this.